# "Java Home" not displayed on running "mvn -v" in cmd

Tags: java, maven

On running "mvn -v" in command prompt, I was initially getting an error saying Java Home is set to JRE and not JDK. I had made sure that I installed JDK 12 from oracle's website (and not a JRE). After several attempts, the error was gone after adding JAVA_HOME as a user variable (it was already added in System variables earlier).

However on running "mvn -v" in command prompt, I am not seeing "Java Home" at all now. My results look like below:

C:\Users\uzmaf>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T14:00:29-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin..
Java version: 12.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

What am I missing here?

Comment: Doesn't it say right there "Java version: 12.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1"?

Comment: May I ask what your issue is? As far as I can see `mvn -v` is doing what it's supposed to do, which is outputting exactly what you listed.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven version 3.6.1 they have removed the "JAVA HOME" property from display in version command but that should not pose any problem as such. You can refer to CLIReportingUtils.showVersion() method in below link:

https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.6.1/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/CLIReportingUtils.java

```
public static String showVersion()
{
    final String ls = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
    Properties properties = getBuildProperties();
    StringBuilder version = new StringBuilder( 256 );
    version.append( buffer().strong( createMavenVersionString( properties ) ) ).append( ls );
    version.append( reduce(
        properties.getProperty( "distributionShortName" ) + " home: " + System.getProperty( "maven.home",
                                                                                            "<unknown Maven "
                                                                                                + "home>" ) ) )
        .append( ls );
    version.append( "Java version: " ).append(
        System.getProperty( "java.version", "<unknown Java version>" ) ).append( ", vendor: " ).append(
        System.getProperty( "java.vendor", "<unknown vendor>" ) ).append( ", runtime: " ).append(
        System.getProperty( "java.home", "<unknown runtime>" ) ).append( ls );
    version.append( "Default locale: " ).append( Locale.getDefault() ).append( ", platform encoding: " ).append(
        System.getProperty( "file.encoding", "<unknown encoding>" ) ).append( ls );
    version.append( "OS name: \"" ).append( Os.OS_NAME ).append( "\", version: \"" ).append( Os.OS_VERSION ).append(
        "\", arch: \"" ).append( Os.OS_ARCH ).append( "\", family: \"" ).append( Os.OS_FAMILY ).append( '\"' );
    return version.toString();
}
```